# expected ';' and instead saw '='

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have many problems

**very long code is that just a part and stackoverflow limiterd 30000 characters **

*first problem* :

**expected ';' and instead saw '='.**

```
var qq = function(a) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        hide: function() {
            return a.style.display = "none", this
        },
        attach: function(b, c) {
            return a.addEventListener ? a.addEventListener(b, c, !1) : a.attachEvent && a.attachEvent("on" + b, c),
                function() {
                    qq(a).detach(b, c)
                }
        }
    }
};
```

*other problems*

**unreachable '=' after 'return'.**

**expected an identifier and instead saw '='.**

Comment: I think you first learn basic JS. As I am seeing you are not familiar with the syntax of it yet.

Comment: can you please add some of the lines before `var qq = function(a) {
?`

Comment: First error: you cannot write `return a.style.display = "none", this` as that is not "one thing".   That looks like you're trying to execute an assignment as part of the return value, which cannot be done.  Maybe `a.style.display = "none"; return this;` ?

Comment: like this `return [a.style.display = "none",this];`instead of `return a.style.display = "none", this`

Comment: this file for just upload avatar

Comment: That `return` statement is problematic and JavaScript can't deal with your bare `,`. You need to return an explicit structure, like @jasinthpremkumar suggests.

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar while that would technically work and pass any linter, it's still not a good idea. Use separate staments.

Answer (score 2):

Think carefully **what are you trying to return exactly**.

It's an array of two elements?

```
return [
   a.style.display === "none", 
   this
];
```

It's an object?

```
return {
   isHidden: (a.style.display === "none"), 
   scope: this
};
```

Are you just setting the display and then returning `this`?

```
  a.style.display = "none";
  return this;
```

You can't return two "things", like `return a,b`

Comment: Third one is simple and solves the problem

Comment: I'm glad. If it solves the problem, then please accept it as best answer.

Comment: Hi. If this answer satisfied the question, please mark it as best answer. Thank you.

Comment: he cant choose , because topic is closed